# Formatting a Census Tract String to xxxxx.xx

Tags: php

I am receiving a census track as "022100".  The proper output should be 0221.00.

What is the best way to format this string in PHP?  I guess I need it to remain as a string since it had a leading zero.  I was originally thinking of multiplying it x .01 and then number formatting it, but that will remove the leading zero.

While substr_replace($response->tract_code, '.', 4, 0) works, I would prefer to rely on counting two positions from the right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$str = "022100";
$offset = strlen($str)-2;
$newstr = substr_replace($str, ".", $offset, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$str = "022100";
$formatStr = preg_replace('/^(.*)(..)$/u','$1.$2',$str);
//string(7) "0221.00"
```